# Query for Collapsing Node in Path with Multiple Relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my DB, my connections between item nodes are done through a three-way node-connection, like the one highlighted below. I chose it this way because I don't think there's a way to do a three-way arrow or relationship.

[image: example graph]

Anyways, I don't think this modeling is a problem in itself. But I would like to query this graph in a way that I ditch the `CONNECTED_BY` relationship and collapse the connection path (e.g. the higlighted node in the picture) down to a simple relationship. How do I do it with Cypher in Neo4j?

I know there's the [`apoc.refactor.collapseNode` procedure](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/collapse-node-to-relationship/), but, as far as I know, it actually mutates the database? Is there a way to use solely as a query? Not to mention that, in my case, I would have to omit the other relationships on the collapsed node somehow.

Here's an example of how to reproduce what I have:

```
// Users

// #1
CREATE (:User{name: "philippe_fanaro"});
CREATE (:User{name: "john_doe"});

// Items

// #1
MATCH  (u:User{name: "john_doe"})
CREATE (u)-[:CREATED]->(:Item{title: "Designing Data-Intensive Applications"});

// #2
MATCH  (u:User{name: "philippe_fanaro"})
CREATE (u)-[:CREATED]->(:Item{title: "System Design Interview – An insider's guide"});

// Connections

// #1
MATCH  (i1:Item), (i2:Item), (u:User{name: "philippe_fanaro"})
WHERE  i1.title CONTAINS "Designing"
  AND  i2.title CONTAINS "System"
CREATE (i1)- [:CONNECTION_ORIGIN]
           ->(c:Connection{title: "Relation"})
           - [:CONNECTION_DESTINATION]->(i2),
       (c)-[:CONNECTED_BY]->(u);
```

Comment: Is there a specific query you want, or generally speaking? Can you provide input parameters for a query and the expected results from your sample data?

Comment: I thought the second paragraph described what I wanted. What should I add in order to make it more clear?

Comment: If just getting rid of the `CONNECTED_BY` relationships from your visualization is an acceptable compromise, your query could just not return any `CONNECTED_BY` relationships (and ensure `Connect result nodes` is unchecked in your Neo4j Browser settings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to query and what you want the result to be. But if you want to do something similar to `apoc.refactor.collapseNode()` but as a virtual path instead of modifying the graph then maybe something like this could work (this query is based on the nodes and relationships you created in your example above with John Doe and Philippe Fanaro and creates a path from the "Designing"-book to the "System"-book with a virtual relationship called ":CONNECTION")?

```
MATCH (n1)-[:CONNECTION_ORIGIN]->(r)-[:CONNECTION_DESTINATION]->(n2)

WITH n1, apoc.create.vRelationship(n1, "CONNECTION", {}, n2) AS rel

RETURN apoc.path.create(n1, [rel])
```

Or, while adding the connection properties into the collapsed relationship and also returning the users:

```
MATCH (n1:Item)
       -[:CONNECTION_ORIGIN]
      ->(r:Connection)
       -[:CONNECTION_DESTINATION]
      ->(n2:Item),
      (r)-[:CONNECTED_BY]-(u:User)

WITH u, 
     n1, 
     apoc.create.vRelationship(
       n1, 
       "CONNECTION", 
       apoc.map.merge(
         properties(r), 
         { connected_by: u.id }
       ), 
       n2
     ) AS rel

RETURN u, apoc.path.create(n1, [rel])
```

Which yields the following:

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I've added some more stuff to it and I think it's all good now. One last thing though: if this graph gets bigger, with more types of relationships that is, how would I succinctly return it while only doing this collapsing. I mean something along the lines of: return everything, but do this collapsing; instead of having to enumerate the rest of the graph in the `MATCH` clause.

Comment: And, if you don't mind: do you think this type of thing is performant?

Comment: Regarding the performance I believe that the traversing of the graph (the MATCH part) is what takes time. The calling of the APOC methods to create the virtual relationships is probably neglecteble, and thus it is down to how optimal the MATCH part is done.